# Why does iPhone Voice Control turn on when I wear headphones while working out?

Tags: iphone, headphones

I listen to music on my iPhone 4 while working out on stair master. After about an hour, voice control turns on by itself. I turn it off but it comes back on. Then the iPod is paused then skips couple songs. It doesn't stop.  I think it has to do with headphones or something. Maybe sweat getting into headphones?  This happens almost every time I work out.

Apparently this is common issue. 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2512674?start=0&tstart=0

https://discussions.apple.com/message/9714491#9714491

Comment: Searching for the same answers as everyone else. Currently sporting an iPhone 6S Plus with the same issues. I took a small piece of tape, doubled it over on itself, and punched a whole in my the tape w a fork, and slid my headphones through the hole. Cut the tape to be a little tighter and just completed a workout w zero interruptions from Siri or voice control

Answer (score 3):

It certainly sounds like the headphones are causing this. It's likely that moisture is eventually getting into the in-line switch/microphone module which is bridging the switch terminals and sending spurious signals to the phone.

However, I'd try the following:

- Check for liquid damage inside the headphone socket: Hold your phone up to the light so that you can see down inside of the headphone port. There's a small indicator at the bottom of the port which will have turned a red/pink colour if liquid has come into contact with it. If positive, this could indicate that the phone's headphone socket may (also) be at fault.
- Obtain another pair of the same Apple headphones and see if the issue occurs again.

Comment: I had a pair of iPhone head phones. Same thing happened to them. I just bought a new pair of Bose head phones. It was the first time I wore them during workout and same thing happened.

Comment: Then all signs point to the phone being at fault. Check the headphone socket for lint, dust or other obstructions (use compressed air (anti-static) to clear it out). Check for liquid damage. If it's still in warranty, take it to an Apple store for replacement.

Comment: Of coarse I'm not the only one https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2512674?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well, much to my frustration. I have since found that it doesn't happen as long as I keep the headphone cable on the outside of my clothing instead of underneath it. When I'm in the gym I used to run the cable down underneath my shirt to stop it catching on things. I think the noise from my shirt rubbing on the microphone my have been activating voice control. Since I started running it down the outside of my clothes into my pocket I have had no issues.

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped the headphone wire where the mic and controls are with a few layers of Saran Wrap. This keeps the sweat out but still allows use of the controls. Used to have the random Siri problem described all the time on long runs, did a hot sweaty 18 mile run today with Saran Wrap and had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my past experience, my recommendation is to power off the phone, recharge it, and see if that fixes the problem.

I had a huge problem with my iPhone 4 where it just kept going to Voice Control. It went on and on all night and called random people in the middle of the night! Not good!

Finally cos it had been so active all day it died on me so I let it. Peace for one night! Anyway the next day when I charged it, it was all working good again and no problems so far.

Answer (score 0):

Tis was a major problem for me and I just blew hard straight into the hole where the headphones go and the problem was fixed for me!

Answer (score -2):

this has happened to me, its is the headphone jack, and it will need to be replacd, its not too expensive. about £30 uk money.